# How to correct this script to don't run triggers on specific dates

Tags: google-apps-script

Im currently using this script

```
function shouldRunTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var fiestas = ss.getSheetByName("x");
  var data = fiestas.getRange(2,1,fiestas.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();
  var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
  var date = new Date();
  var day = days[date.getDay()];
  var hours = date.getHours();  
  var FiestaEmpieza = date
  var FiestaAcaba = date
  for (var row in data){    
     FiestaEmpieza = data[row][2] ;
    }
  for (var row in data){    
     FiestaAcaba = data[row][3] ;
    }
  // Don't run from Friday 6pm until Saturday 10Pm
   if ((day === "Fri" && hours >= 18) || (day === "Sat" && hours <= 21)){
    return false;
  }

  // Dont turn from specific dates from Tab "x" from 6pm until 10pm
   else if (date >= FiestaEmpieza && hours >= 18 && date <= FiestaAcaba && hours <= 21){
    return false; 
  }

   else {
    return true; 
  }

}
```

The purpose of the script: I have to run some triggers every 5 mins, but if the day is between Friday 6pm and Saturday 10pm the trigger doesn't run This part is working.

I need also this to don't run in specific dates (line 31 of the script) 
which takes dates from my spreadsheet Tab "x" , the Start date is Column C and the End date is Column D, and the data looks like this:

[image]

The problem I believe is the line 31 of the script

```
else if (date >= FiestaEmpieza && hours >= 18 && date <= FiestaAcaba && hours <= 21){
```

Which is not detecting the Dates and Hrs correctly , I'm not sure if the && are correct.

Any help on how to solve this please ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work.  If I can have access to your spreadsheet so that I can just copy the data then I would test it.

```
function shouldRunTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("x");
  var vA=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();
  var days=["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
  var today=new Date();
  var day=days[today.getDay()];
  var hours=today.getHours();  
  if((day=="Fri" && hours>=18) || (day=="Sat" && hours<=22)){return false;}
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){    
    var dt1=new Date(vA[row][2]).valueOf();
    var dt2=new Date(vA[row][3]).valueOf();
    if(today.valueOf()>=dt1 && hours >=18 && today.valueOf() <= dt2 && hours <= 21){
      return false; 
    }
  }
  return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`FiestaEmpeiza` y `FiestaAcaba` will always be the last row because you loop through the date values and assign, but then don't perform any of your conditional checks. You need to consolidate the loops into one, and then move your if statements into the loop.

I recommend changing some of the variable names to be more descriptive and pass the trigger time to your function so that you can more easily test it.

Also, make sure that you maintain consistency with your date checks–date objects include time. The way you had it written, you were comparing dates objects, meaning that "April 1 @ 4pm" is earlier than "April 1 @ 4:01pm". So your condition could fail depending on the value you had defined in `date`. You can fix this simply by [setting hours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours). (Be careful with time zone issues.)

```
function test_shouldRunTrigger() {
  var triggerTime = new Date("Fri Apr 19 17:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019"); // Change the date to test
  Logger.log(shouldRunTrigger(triggerTime));
}

function shouldRunTrigger(triggerTime) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("x");
  var fiestas = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();
  var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
  var triggerDay = days[triggerTime.getDay()]; // Day of the week
  var triggerHour = triggerTime.getHours(); // Hour of the trigger
  var triggerDate = new Date(triggerTime.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)); // Set time to 00:00:00
  Logger.log(fiestas)
  for (var row in fiestas) {
    var fiestaEmpieza = new Date(fiestas[row][2].setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)); // Set time to 00:00:00
    var fiestaAcaba = new Date(fiestas[row][3].setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)); // Set time to 00:00:00

    // Don't run from Friday 6pm until Saturday 10pm
    if ((triggerDay === "Fri" && triggerHour >= 18) || (triggerDay === "Sat" && triggerHour <= 21)) {
      return false;
    } else if ( // Dont run from specific dates from Tab "x" from 6pm until 10pm
      triggerDate >= fiestaEmpieza && // Compares dates and we know the times are all 00:00:00
      triggerHour >= 18 &&
      triggerDate <= fiestaAcaba && // Compares dates and we know the times are all 00:00:00
      triggerHour <= 21
    ) { 
      return false; 
    } else {
      return true; 
    }
  }
}
```